# Problem with my update statement --getting error 3144

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am getting Runtime error 3144 Syntax error in update statement when I am running this code and not sure what I am doing wrong.  I have a list that I am wanting to write to another table (my main table) in my database.  Below is the code:

```
Set lst = Me.lstTermEmpl

For Each item In lst.ItemsSelected
    CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE tbl_Staffing SET Term_Heat_Ticket_Num = me.TxtTerm_Heat_Ticket_Num, Inactive_Status_Dt =lst.column(7), Termination_Reason_FK =lst.column(9), WHERE ID = " & _
        lst.Column(8) & ";", dbFailOnError
```

It is retruning values for the me.TxtTerm_Heat_Ticket_num and the Inactive_Status_dt but Not the Termination_Reason_FK or the ID.

Am I missing something in the code maybe?

This is my query for my list:

```
SELECT Tbl_Term_Employees.Term_ID, Tbl_Term_Employees.Date_of_TermEmplRequest,
Tbl_Term_Employees.NatGen_ID, Tbl_Term_Employees.FirstName, 
Tbl_Term_Employees.LastName, IIf([Term_Approval_Status]=0,"Pending SVM Approval","SVM Approved") AS TermApprovalStatus, 
Tbl_Termination_Reasons.Termination_Reason, 
Tbl_Term_Employees.Inactive_Status_Dt, Tbl_Term_Employees.ID_FK, 
Tbl_Term_Employees.Termination_Reason_FK, Tbl_Term_Employees.Team_Fk, 
Tbl_Term_Employees.Site_FK
FROM ((Tbl_Term_Employees INNER JOIN Tbl_Termination_Reasons ON Tbl_Term_Employees.Termination_Reason_FK = Tbl_Termination_Reasons.Termination_Reason_ID) INNER JOIN Tbl_Teams ON Tbl_Term_Employees.Team_Fk = Tbl_Teams.Team_ID) INNER JOIN Tbl_Site ON Tbl_Term_Employees.Site_FK = Tbl_Site.Site_ID
WHERE (((Tbl_Term_Employees.Team_Fk)=[forms]![FrmTermEmplList].[cboTeam]) AND ((Tbl_Term_Employees.Site_FK)=[forms]![FrmTermEmplList].[cboSite]) AND ((Tbl_Term_Employees.Term_Approval_Status)=[forms]![FrmTermEmplList].[txtTerm_Approval_Status]));
```

[image]--Picture of my query in design view

Comment: Really don't see how can return any of the non-concatenated variable values.

Answer (score 1):

Concatenate variable input. Reference to form control is a variable.
Semi-colon ";" is not needed.
Remove comma in front of WHERE.

Parameter for date/time type field needs # delimiters, text field parameter needs apostrophes.

```
    CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE tbl_Staffing SET Term_Heat_Ticket_Num = '" & _
        Me.TxtTerm_Heat_Ticket_Num & "', Inactive_Status_Dt = #" & lst.column(7, item) & _
        "#, Termination_Reason_FK = " & lst.column(9, item) & " WHERE ID = " & lst.Column(8, item), dbFailOnError
```

Comment: The code above is still showing null for my termination_reason_FK and 0 on my ID.  Could it be the query for the list that is not returning the values of the columns?

Comment: The sql for my query is this:  However I am not sure if I am pulling in the primary key from the tbl_Staffing which is ID.

Comment: SQL is too long for this box

Comment: The list box keeps giving me a null value for the Termination_Reason_FK even though the table the query for the list box runs from has a value in that field.  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I added my query that produces my list.

Comment: I am pulling in the value of the ID from the staffing table and the value of the Termination_Reason_FK in the table that feeds into the list.  I just dont know why I can't get the value of the Termination_Reason_FK to populate instead of giving me a null

Comment: Are you sure those values are in listbox columns? Open the RowSource SELECT query in designer - is data there?

Comment: Hi June7, it is still showing my Termination_Reason_FK = null.  everything else is returning what it should in the execute line but that one.  I thought I had the wrong column number but it is still showing as null.

Comment: I added a picture to my original question with the design view of the query and it has data.  I counted the columns to the Termination_Reason_FK and it is in column 10 in the query list however I changed it in the code from a 9 to a 10 and it is still showing a null value even though it has data in that column

Comment: Code syntax I provided is correct. Reference to column index 9 is correct (index begins with 0). I have no idea why data will not pull because I do not know your database.

Comment: What would be my next steps on getting this resolved.  I am new to VBA coding and just want this to work.

Comment: Provide db for analysis. Providing files is not encouraged on SO. Try getting assistance at another forum where providing files is.

Comment: If I wanted to take the Termination_Reason_FK out of the statement how would the code look?  I keep getting syntax errors when I take that piece out.

Comment: `CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE tbl_Staffing SET Term_Heat_Ticket_Num = '" & _
        Me.TxtTerm_Heat_Ticket_Num & "', Inactive_Status_Dt = #" & lst.column(7, item) & _
        "# WHERE ID = " & lst.Column(8, item), dbFailOnError`